# Google analytics without using any library

Tags: android, google-analytics

In a special scenario, I would like to do the `google analytics` in android code, **without using the google analytics library**.

Is this possible? If yes, how to program it from scratch.

Otherwise is there a simpler pure HTTP based analytics system as open source? which can be coded using a normal `URLConnection`

Otherwise is it possible to do google analytics using `URLConnection`, if yes, how?

Comment: Why do you need this. Most of work is done by google for us. Why do you want to reinvent a bicycle?

Comment: It is really unfortunate that, it is a special scenario which I am currently in RND

Comment: I am interresting what can happen to not allow to use GA library?

Comment: You could use the measurement protocol to send bare http request to the Google servers, but you'd need to plan for so many prerequisites and contingencies (from obtaining a user identifier to queueing data during offline usage) that you will have a huge amount of work in front of you (well beyond what could be answered in an SO post) and you'd still end up with something that is very close to the Google SDK. So I'd say this is to broad to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Analytics directly over HTTP (and thus, `URLConnection`).

You can find the documentation here : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/